# How to use cfqueryparam and NOT NULL

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, notnull, cfqueryparam

I have 2 queries and I want to use the `<cfqueryparam>` tag on it but am not sure how to do it for this query:

```
    <cfif isdefined("FORM.chk3g")>
        ThreeG IS NOT NULL AND
    </cfif>

    <cfif isdefined("FORM.chkpolyphonic")>
        ringtonetype like '%polyphonic%' AND
    </cfif>
```

Comment: Is `polyphonic` a constant or a `#variable#`? There is really [no benefit to using cfqueryparam with constants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574276/how-can-cfqueryparam-affect-performance-for-constants-and-null-values/17582859#17582859).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<cfif isdefined("FORM.chk3g")>
    ThreeG IS NOT NULL AND
</cfif>

<cfif isdefined("FORM.chkpolyphonic")>
    ringtonetype like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="%polyphonic%"> AND
</cfif>
```