# How can <cfqueryparam> affect performance for constants and null values?

Tags: coldfusion, null, oracle11g, coldfusion-9, cfqueryparam

Consider the following:

```
<cfquery name="aQuery" datasource="#aSource#">
    SELECT aColumn
      FROM aTable
     WHERE bColumn = <cfqueryparam value="#aVariable#" cfsqltype="#aSqlType#" />
       AND cColumn = 'someConstant'
       AND dColumn is null
</cfquery>
```

If I change

```
AND cColumn = 'someConstant'
```

to

```
AND cColumn = <cfqueryparam value="someConstant" cfsqltype="#aSqlType#" />
```

Is there a potential performance improvement? Is there potential to hurt performance?

What if I do the same (use cfqueryparam) with `AND dColumn is null`?

My findings have been inconclusive.

If it's important, assume ColdFusion9 and Oracle db 11g.

EDIT:

I'd just like to reiterate that I'm asking about cfqueryparam tags being used specifically with constants and/or null values and the performance remifications, if any.

Comment: using a cfqueryparam with a cfsqltype can help the database optimize itself, so it knows to expect an int or a varchar, etc which can speed up database queries

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference but the best way to find out it to test it.  The result attribute of cfquery gives you the execution time.  Run two queries 1000 or so times inside a loop.  Put the execution times into an array and then compare the averages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a potential performance improvement?

No. Bind variables are most useful when *varying* parameters are involved. Without them, the database would generate a new execution plan every time the query parameters changed (which is expensive). Bind variables encourage the database to cache and reuse a *single* execution plan, even when the parameters change. This saves the cost of compiling, boosting performance. There is really no benefit with *constants*. Since the value never changes, the database will always reuse the execution plan. So there is not much reason to use it on constants.

> Is there potential to hurt performance?

I have a seen a few mentions of special cases where using bind variables on constants may actually degrade performance. But that is really on a case-by-case basis.

- http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/04/02/scenario-for-using-a-constant-instead-of-a-bind-variable-in-an-oltp-system/
- http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:24110#121568

Comment: The worst scenario is using mixed cfqueryparam with a query that uses non-parametrized variables in SQL -- especially when there are a lot of variations in the non-parametrized variables. Either make all your variables in SQL cfqueryparams (preferred) or make all variables without cfqueryparam. Constants/Nulls don't matter as Leigh answered. Using mixed can hurt performance on high volume sites. Low volume apps won't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, since you already have one `<cfqueryparam>` and that will turn it into a prepared statement, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score -2):

Using a query param will help in 2 ways.

First, it will protect you from SQLI.  It will add a level of protection to make sure that the data in the param is what is expected.

Secondly, you will see a performance increase.  However, the increase depends on the data schema and indexes.  The param will allow for the database to cache the query plan.  This speeds up the initial overhead of the query execution.  The more complex the query, the more important is becomes to cache the query plan.

Also, make sure you have a covering indexes for all the columns in the where clause and that they are in the correct order.  If not, the query optimizer may opt to ignore the indexes and go directly to doing table scans.