# magic_quotes_gpc setting for ColdFusion? ColdBox?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I am new to ColdFusion and want to remove single quotes from the values of my input fields. I tried to search on google and what I found is to use "magic_quotes_gpc" or  "mysql_real_escape_string" but those functions do not exist in ColdFusion. Is there any way to handle this kind of mysql query injection in ColdFusion?

**Updated:**

Thank you for reply but please look at my code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="jobDesc">Job description</label>
    <textarea name="description" class="form-control" rows="3" id="jobDesc">
        <cfif isdefined('userTime')>#userTime.description#</cfif>        
   </textarea>
</div>
```

I just want to use single quotes in the text area and my form is submitting to event. The query is:

```
 sqlstr = "";
          sqlstr = "insert into usertime set
          userid = '#arguments.userTimeParams.userid#',
          projectid = '#arguments.userTimeParams.projectid#',
          timesheetdate = '#arguments.userTimeParams.timesheetdate#',
          estimatedtimespent = '#arguments.userTimeParams.jobhours * 60 + arguments.userTimeParams.jobMins#',
          description = '#arguments.userTimeParams.description#',
          timeentered = #arguments.userTimeParams.timeentered#;";

            queryObj = new query();
            queryObj.setDatasource("timesheet");
            queryObj.setName("adduserTime");
            result = queryObj.execute(sql=sqlstr);
            adduserTime = result.getResult();
            return result.getPrefix().generatedKey;
```

I have one option that I can add slashes to my string, but then I have to add slashes in all strings. So is there any function or way to do this with less lines of code?

Sorry for asking much with limited knowledge.

Comment: Use the [cfqueryparam](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfqueryparam) tag (or script equivalent).  Among other things, it will escape the quotes for you.

Comment: FYI, those features you mention were huge design mistakes that the PHP folks already fixed years ago. You need to use prepared statements, no matter the client language.

Comment: @ Alvaro, i have been through a lot links and i know they fixed in php but i din found any solution in cf till yet so i asked..anyway thanx for your PRECIOUS commant

Comment: Regarding, `wanted to remove single quotes from the values of my input fields`, that's probably a bad idea.  A single quote has the same ascii value as an apostrophe.  These are used in contractions and surnames.  You've already been told about query parameters, the path to happiness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um... just don't pass your user input (or any other data ~) values hard-coded in your SQL statements, pass them as parameter values instead.

Example:

```
coloursViaQueryExecute = queryExecute("
    SELECT  en AS english, mi AS maori
    FROM    colours
    WHERE   id BETWEEN :low AND :high 
    ",
    {low=URL.low, high=URL.high},
    {datasource="scratch_mssql"}
);
```

Where `low` and `high` are your parameters.

See relevant docs @ [QueryExecute()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/QueryExecute)

And further reading on the topic:

- [What one can and cannot do with `<cfqueryparam>`](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/07/what-one-can-and-cannot-do-with.html)
- [`Query.cfc` / `queryExecute()` have a good feature `<cfquery>` lacks](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/03/querycfc-queryexecute-have-good-feature.html)

Comment: I realize the above is just an example, but you should definitely add a parameter "type" as well. Otherwise, the values are sent as strings and the database ends up performing implicit conversion, [which does not always produce the desired results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049918/coldfusion-parameterizing-a-querie/27066113#27066113). (Edit) BTW, nice entry on parameter do's and don'ts :)

Answer (score 4):

Without parameterizing the user data, you are opening yourself to SQL injection. The `REReplace()` may not catch everything. Here is how you should rewrite that code to use `cfqueryparam`. You may need to tweak the `addParam()` method calls to add the correct `cfsqltype`.

```
sqlstr = "";
      sqlstr = "insert into usertime set
      userid = :userid,
      projectid = :projectid,
      timesheetdate = :timesheetdate,
      estimatedtimespent = :estimatedtimespent,
      description = :description,
      timeentered = :timeentered";

        queryObj = new query();
        queryObj.setDatasource("timesheet");
        queryObj.setName("adduserTime");
        queryObj.addParam( name="userid", value=arguments.usertimeparams.userid);
        queryObj.addParam( name="projectid", value=arguments.usertimeparams.projectid);
        queryObj.addParam( name="timesheetdate", value=arguments.usertimeparams.timesheetdate, cfsqltype="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP");
        queryObj.addParam( name="estimatedtimspent", value=arguments.userTimeParams.jobhours * 60 + arguments.userTimeParams.jobMins, cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER");
        queryObj.addParam( name="description", value=arguments.usertimeparams.description);
        queryObj.addParam( name="timeentered", value=arguments.usertimeparams.timeentered, cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER");
        result = queryObj.execute(sql=sqlstr);
        adduserTime = result.getResult();
        return result.getPrefix().generatedKey;
```

Comment: That's a lot more code than you need mate. You don't need to attach the parameter values one at a time. See example here: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/01/using-querycfc-doesnt-have-to-be-drama.html

Comment: Understood, but thought it might be easier to understand what was being done if I added each separately.

Comment: Yep. [Escaping quotes is definitely not bullet-proof](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18797042/104223). As Scott and Adam said, you need to use "parameterized" sql.

Comment: @ scott thanx but this code is not working..i tried and getting error after  queryObj.addParam( name="userid", ...) lines as it says Element USERTIMPARAMS.PROJECTID is undefined in ARGUMENTS. but i checked with dump and got all value..may be not the correct way to write addParam..??

Comment: Oops, there was a typo. I mis-named the variable. I just fixed the code.